# Bootstrap dynamically loaded buttons not clickable iOS/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

It works fine on Android and PC/Mac. But for some reason, when I dynamically load in buttons on iOS, I can't click them. It seems that none of the javascript runs on dynamically loaded content. Here is the code, it should work:

```
favbutton = $('<button class = "btn favbutton pull-right btn-lg" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Favorited!"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true" style = "vertical-align:middle"></span></button>');
...
well.append(favbutton);
well.children(".favbutton").on("click", function(event){
    //code here, never even reaches it
});
```

Comment: You also dynamically load buttons in PC/MAC, and it's still working?

Comment: Yes, and it also works on all the Android devices I've tested. I've tried on the iPad, iPad Air, iPhones 5, 5s, 6, 6+, and none of the dynamically loaded content works. However, the statically loaded buttons work just fine.